# route traffic from a cgroup via a specific network interface

Tags: iptables, cgroup

Is there a possiblity, to restrict a cgroup to a specific network interface? All packets from the cgroup should only be routed via a VPN connection, while other packets use the default route.

With unix users its possible with iptables "-m owner --set-mark" and then routing with "ip rule".

Is it possible to match a cgroup? iptables seems to have no support for this.

Comment: See both commits for an example: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/net/netfilter/xt_cgroup.c?id=82a37132f300ea53bdcd812917af5a6329ec80c3 https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/net/netfilter/xt_cgroup.c?id=a00e76349f3564bb8129fc0510dfd93248c3084d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iptables support for -m cgroup has not yet been released, but you can easily build the extension yourself and install it on your system:

```
git clone git://git.netfilter.org/iptables.git
cd iptables
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -k
sudo cp extensions/libxt_cgroup.so /lib/xtables/
sudo chmod -x /lib/xtables/libxt_cgroup.so
```

Comment: Depending on your system, you may also do the same for git.netfilter.org/libnftnl/ (`...; make -k; sudo make install`) and do a `autoreconf -fi` before running configure. This is for debian jessie.

Comment: First install pre-requisites `sudo apt-get install dh-autoreconf bison flex`.Then,  I recommend using [these build instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/postlfs/iptables.html) to avoid several build errors. Especially use `./configure --disable-nftables` flag and `make install`.

Comment: Works with debian unstable iptables binary. Great!

Comment: "iptables support for -m cgroup has not yet been released" -- how did you not this? Not doubting, but would like to know how you were able to find this out.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-m cgroup`.  Example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup ! --cgroup 1 -j DROP
```

From: http://lwn.net/Articles/569678/

Comment: I guess this is what i searched, seems it was not supported by my kernel in dec 2013. I will check back and mark as accepted when i had time to test it. Where do i get the cgroup id, i.e. for a lxc container?

Comment: I tested it, it does not work on debian jessie. The xt_cgroup module is there, but iptables with ``-m cgroup`` does not find the match target and the ``net_filter`` mount does not work either. I guess i need to investigate, if some of the apis changed afterwards. Or check if ``cgroup/net_cls`` is useful.